# How to run script in parent window for child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `child.html` have a button which could click using script `$('[value="Submit"]').click();`
I want to invoke this from `parent.html`

Something like this:

`var popUp = window.open('https://child.html');
 popUp.$('[value="Submit"]').click();` //this line should be fixed

How could do this?

Comment: Actually your line should work (assuming you're on the same domain so that you have access to the child window). What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in parent.html to click button:

```
let child = window.open('child.html');
let doClick = () => child.document.getElementById('my-button').click();

child.addEventListener('load', doClick(), true);
```

This is what you want... But my suggestion is to make function on child and use window.postMessage API to trigger it...

Comment: TypeError:Cannot read property 'click' of null. Could you help me to add load event listener in this code? Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, this happens because document is not loaded yet, but that only happens if this script is executed automatically in root of script, but if you are invoking it by some action like another button click, it will work, please describe how you want to trigger that button click, so I can edit my answer properly.

Comment: Hi, I would like to trigger it automatically after completing loading. I know its not sync each other, still I believe there will be a solution.

Comment: Still the same error. Ticking as most preferred solution.

Comment: Not sure how you are getting this error, could you share you code? Have you added id="my-button" to your button or have you changed selector used in my code accordingly to your button id or class?

Comment: I am trying this way,
let child = window.open('child.html');
let doClick = () => $('[value="Submit"]').click();

child.addEventListener('load', doClick(), true); Tried as child.document.getElementById('my-button').click(); too. Still not working.

Comment: Please, use plain javascript, use child.document.getElementById('my-button').click(); and change id of your input/button to "my-button", or something else, but then be sure to change selector passed to getElementById.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API. Here is example code.

child.html

```
function functionToBeExecuted(event)
{
  // do click or whatever you want
}

window.addEventListener("message", functionToBeExecuted, false);
```

parent.html

```
let child = window.open('child.html');

child.postMessage(); // notice that I did not pass message argument, since you just want to trigger the function, but if you want to pass some data to function using event parameter, just pass data to this function (for example string or object etc.)
```

Comment: Thanks. This may be useful for many. But, I am looking for child.html with zero script

Comment: Use this in parent: child.document.getElementById('my-button').click(). And I have posted another answer, which answers your question with zero script in child.html.

Answer (score 2):

I went in a similar kind of issue where I had iframe(containing child html) inside my parent html.
I solved this  $(".DivClass iframe").contents().find("button").trigger('click');
 In your case its pop window I don't no which popup you are using: custom pop or browser pop.
You can Add iframe inside your popup to achieve this issue using the same code as what I did.
**Condition is that popup should be custom html popup not the other popup which is provided by browser provide**.

Comment: do you have an example code or something about iframe mentioned above? Thanks

Comment: Sorry rash I was out over the weekend. If you want still help on this I can.